# How to run commands on a variable containing a date?

Tags: bash, date

I need to be able to take a date in the format of "MM/DD/YY" and change it back into the default date format (Fri Oct 31 17:23:07 CDT 2014).  This is driving me crazy.  The code below may look pointless, but it's just practice for an assignment where I have to do this exact thing - Someone enters a date in the format of MM/DD/YY, then I have to compare that date to dates stored in a file in the default format.

Here's where I'm at:

```
#! /bin/bash

date=`date +%D`
newdate=`$date +%a%b%e%H:%M:%S%Z%Y`

echo $newdate
```

I'm getting a "No Such File or Directory" error.  First off; how would I do what I'm trying to do?  Second; is there an easier way to use to the default date format instead of "+%a%b%e...blah blah..."?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You would likely find it easier to spot your error if you didn't use the same name (`date`) for your variable as for the command whose output you are assigning

Comment: Try to change `newdate=$(date -d "$date" "+%a%b%e%H:%M:%S%Z%Y")`

Comment: Second: default machine date format is the "second since EPOCH(1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC)" with easy convertible to other format. Please note that when you use just `%D` you totally miss hours,minutes and seconds

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to do your homework for you, but this might point you in the right direction:

```
#!/bin/sh

date=`date +%D`
echo "Date in MM/DD/YY:"
echo $date

newdate=`date -d $date +"%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"`
echo "Date Expanded:"
echo $newdate

hash="$(echo -n "$newdate" | md5sum | awk '{print $1}')"
echo "Hash of expanded date:"
echo $hash
```

You can create hash values of all the expanded dates, including the ones you will need to compare them with and then just compare the two hash values. If the `==` then you have a match.

```
if [ "$hash1" == "$hash2" ]
then
    echo "Dates are a match!"
else
    echo "Dates are NOT a match..."
fi
```